# Why give a typename template parameter a default value of 0 in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

### The short version (Read if you have no patience like  me):

What does setting a typename template parameter to a default of 0 do in C++?

My enable if struct:

```
/**
 * @brief Can be used to enable a template definition using a boolean value
 */
template<lfBool Condition>
struct lfEnableIf
{ };

template<>
struct lfEnableIf<true>
{
   typedef lfInt Type;
};
```

My boolen constant struct:

```
template<lfBool Val>
struct lfBoolConstant
{
    static const lfBool Value = Val;    
};

typedef lfBoolConstant<true> lfTrueType;
typedef lfBoolConstant<false> lfFalseType;
```

My type trait struct (just one of the specializations):

```
template <typename NumT> struct lfIsArithmetic : lfFalseType{};

template <> struct lfIsArithmetic<lfChar> : lfTrueType{};
```

And finally my usage of it all:

```
template<typename T, typename lfEnableIf<lfIsArithmetic<T>::Value>::Type = 0>
struct Test
{
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << "OK!" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Test<lfFloat>::print();
    Test<lfBool>::print();

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the poor for formatting I am writing this on my cell phone.

### The long version (Please read if you have the patience so you understand why there is not much code):

So, I am on vacation and don't have access to my workstation or laptop so I thought I would try out AIDE, which if you are unaware is an IDE for android that can compile C++. At home I am designing a game engine that includes Boost and I figured I would try to create something similar to the `enable_if` structures that are in the Boost.Core library. I got it mostly working but it would not compile unless I set the enable if structure in the template I was enabling to default to 0! This is what you do with the Boost `enable_if` and `disable_if` templates. So what does setting a typename template parameter to a default of 0 do in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: The example you provided is invalid. There's no such feature in C++. A template *value* parameter of appropriate type would accept a default argument `0`, but that would not be a `typename` parameter. E.g. `template <int N = 0> struct S {};`.

Comment: You can't do this. The default parameter can be _a type_, not a number in this case.

Comment: Are you sure it wans't `<typename SomeType = void>` or something like `typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_pointer< T >, int >::type = 0`

Comment: @AnT look again i typed it wrong

Comment: @Zack Frost: The *current* example is invalid. So it is still wrong.

Comment: I abreviated it. I am writing on a phone whicn is difficulyt. Sprry.

Comment: I will modify it further to show what I have in my code.

Comment: @ZackFrost We don't appreciate this kind of moving targets. Next time post a [MCVE] at first shot please (you still don't provide one BTW).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This line

```
template<typename T, typename lfEnableIf<lfIsArithmetic<T>::Value>::Type = 0>
```

declares a named template *type* parameter `T` and a nameless template *value* parameter of type `lfEnableIf<lfIsArithmetic<T>::Value>::Type`, i.e. the second parameter declarations is basically a more convoluted version of simple

```
template <int N = 0> struct S {};
```

The type `lfEnableIf<lfIsArithmetic<T>::Value>::Type` resolves into type `lfInt` when the enabling condition is met, meaning that the whole thing in such cases is equivalent to

```
template<typename T, lfInt = 0>
```

However, since type of that second template parameter is a *nested* type of a dependent template `lfEnableIf`, you are required to use the keyword `typename` to tell the compiler that member `Type` actually refers to a *type* and not to something else (i.e. to disambiguate the situation).

Again, the second parameter of the template is nameless, but you can give it a name, if you wish. It won't change anything

```
template<typename T, typename lfEnableIf<lfIsArithmetic<T>::Value>::Type V = 0>
```

In the above example I called it `V`. The name of that parameter is not used anywhere in the template, which is why there's no real need to specify it explicitly. It is a dummy parameter, which is also the reason it has a dummy default value (you can replace `0` with `42` - it won't change anything either).

In this case keyword `typename` creates a misleading similarity between the two parameter declarations of your template. In reality in these parameter declarations the keyword `typename` serves two very very very different unrelated purposes.

In the fist template parameter declaration - `typename T` - it declares `T` as a template *type* parameter. In this role keyword `typename` can be replaced with keyword `class`

```
template <class T, ...
```

In the second declaration - `typename lfEnableIf<lfIsArithmetic<T>::Value>::Type = 0` - it serves a secondary purpose - it just tells the compiler that `lfEnableIf<lfIsArithmetic<T>::Value>::Type` is a *type* and thus turns the whole thing into a *value* parameter declaration. In this role keyword `typename` cannot be replaced with keyword `class`.

Comment: Now I understand! So the second parameter can be assigned zero because the enable if template defines "Type" as lfInt which is just a typedef for int. Okay thanks. Sorry it took so long to so sort that out!

Comment: Do you happen to know whether this is SFINAE-safe? I.e when you use `Test` like in `template<typename T> Test<T> f(T t) { return  { }; }`, and call `f("hello")`, does it SFINAE fail or does it fail hard?  If the enable-if were given as a default template argument, it would fail hard I think, because the default argument instantiation is treated as an own definition instantiation. But what if the SFINAE is buried in the parameter declaration like this?

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Yes, you are right. The technique can be used to enable/disable *specializations*.  Trying to use it in the primary template will not achieve anything useful.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: I'd expect it to fail hard, but I can't say I have a supporting quote.

Comment: @AnT ah interesting, it works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/765fbf49a1807d11